# Java split by comma in string containing whitespace

Tags: java, split

I have a below string which I want to split by ',' only and also want to separate 3rd index which is (1005,111222) of each line .

```
1002,USD,04/09/2019,1005,1,cref,,,,,,,,,
1001,USD,11/04/2018,111222,10,reftpt001,SHA,Remittance Code,BCITIT31745,,,RTGS,,,,
```

I am using code down below :

```
List<String> elements = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> elements2 = new ArrayList<String>();
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer((String) object);
while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                    String[] row = st.nextToken().split(",");
                    if (row.length == 5) {
                        elements.add(row[3]);
                    }
                    if (row.length == 12) {
                        elements2.add(row[3]);
                    }
                }
```

In the above string, There is a space between '`Remittance Code`' but it is splitting till `remittance` and after that, it counts the code a new line or string. Please advise how can I skip the white space as it is.

Answer (score 2):

There is no apparent need for `StringTokenizer` here, and the `nextToken()` call stops at the first space. Instead I suggest calling `output.split(",")` directly like

```
String[] row = ((String) object).split("\\s*,\\s*", -1);
```

And remove the [`StringTokenizer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html), **note** the JavaDoc explicitly says *`StringTokenizer` is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the `split` method of `String` or the java.util.regex package instead.*

Answer (score 0):

First you can split with, and then use trim operation

Comment: tried this but also not works: String[] row = st.nextToken().trim().split(",");

Answer (score 0):

```
String stringToSplit= "1001,ZAR,11/04/2018,111222,10,reftpt001,SHA,Remittance Code,BCITIT31745,,,RTGS,,,,"; 
StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(stringToSplit, ","); 
while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) { System.out.println(tokenizer.nextToken()); }
```

Output :

> 1001 ZAR 11/04/2018 111222 10 reftpt001 SHA Remittance Code
>   BCITIT31745 RTGS

Answer (score 0):

I tried with this code:

1st approach :

```
String str = "1001,ZAR,11/04/2018,111222,10,reftpt001,SHA,Remittance Code,BCITIT31745";
String[] words = str.split(",");
for(String word : words) {
   System.out.println(word);
}
```

2nd approach :

```
String str = "1001,ZAR,11/04/2018,111222,10,reftpt001,SHA,Remittance Code,BCITIT31745";
StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(str, ",");
while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens())
{
  System.out.println(tokenizer.nextToken());
}
```

Output :

```
11/04/2018
111222
10
reftpt001
SHA
Remittance Code
BCITIT31745
```

Hope this helps you. :)

Comment: in second approach complete string splits with ',' and when it comes to nexttoken the only string it shows is 1002 than if condition goes failed